# How to convert Docker Image to OCI Format?

Tags: docker, containers, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How do you convert a Docker Image created with e.g. `Docker build .`  to the OCI Format or other formats?

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify use `docker save -o output-file.tar image-name:tag`

As it **always** saves images in the OCI (Open Container Initiative) format, which is the default format used by Docker for saving images.

The resulting output is a *tar* archive containing the `image layers and metadata`.

---

**Explanation:**

`docker save`: This command is used to save one or more images to a tar archive (which is the default OCI format).

`-o output-file.tar`: This option specifies the output file where the image will be saved. Replace output-file.tar with the desired file name.

`image-name:tag`: Replace this with the name and tag of the Docker image you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is quite simple. You would simply create a container for the image.
Next you would use the `docker export command`.
More information can be read from `docker export --help`.

Comment: What are the exact commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/) to change the image format.

```
skopeo copy -f <FORMAT> docker://<SOURCE_REGISTRY>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<TAG> docker://<SOURCE_REGISTRY>/<NEW_IMAGE_NAME>:<NEW_TAG>
```

This will download the image and upload the image in a possibly new format.

`FORMAT` can be `oci`, `v2s1`, or `v2s2`

Example:

```
skopeo copy -f oci docker://registry.company.com/myimage:mytag docker://registry.company.com/myimage:mytag-oci
```

For this the source image needs to be uploaded to a registry.